# ngrx/store - losing data after page reload in angular 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

Anyone please resolve my problem.

Without using localstorage how to keep the data after page reload in angular 4.

```
this.store.select('name');
```

`store.select` return null after page reload.

Comment: Since you seem to be using ngrx, you can combine it with... https://github.com/btroncone/ngrx-store-localstorage

Comment: Everything is lost after a page reload unless you store it into your browser storage.

Comment: @overcl9ck is there any other way to get values without storing in browser..

Comment: If you really don't want to use the browser, you have to use the server.

Comment: U can. Just subscribe to the store..and get the values u want with a filter operator. That way... u call the store directly on page refresh.

Comment: Can you able to give any example using subscribe?

Comment: You can't you need to understand how refresh works, when refresh is performed, browser calls on the server for a fresh copy of the page and its components. Your only options is sessionStorage or localStorage.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way is with localstorage, if you do not, you can use these dependencies to solve this, synchronize ngrx store with localstorage.

- https://github.com/un33k/ngrx-store-localstorage
- https://github.com/larscom/ngrx-store-storagesync